# stuck sending file from client to server

Tags: java, server, client

I have a client which is supposed to download an image file encrypted with AES (I'm not sure if I'm even implementing this correctly) from a server. However, with the following codes, the server gets stuck at the "Sending image" print message without moving on to the "Done" print message. In other words, I can't download the image file. Why is this so?

**Server.java**

```
public class Server { 

    public static void main (String [] args ) throws InvalidKeyException, IOException, Exception { 
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(15123);
        Socket socket = null;
        //start of AES
        //Generate AES Key
        int sizeofkey = 128;
        KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        //initialize with sizeofkey
        kg.init(sizeofkey);
        Key mykey = kg.generateKey();
        System.out.println("AES Key Generated");
        //create cipher object & initialize with generated key
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, mykey);

        while(true) {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString() + " <-> /127.0.0.1:15123" );

            OutputStream sos = socket.getOutputStream();

            // get the image from a webcam
            URL myimage = new URL("http://183.76.13.58:80/SnapshotJPEG?Resolution=640x480");

            //Picture in string format
            //String plainpic = null;

            //Picture in byte array format
            byte[] plainpic = null;
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            InputStream is = null;
            try {
                //in = new DataInputStream(myimage.openStream()); 



                is = myimage.openStream ();
                byte[] byteChunk = new byte[4096]; 
                int n;

                while ( (n = is.read(byteChunk)) > 0 ) {
                    baos.write(byteChunk, 0, n);
                }

                //Picture in string format
                //plainpic=Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(baos.toByteArray());

                //Picture in byte array format
                plainpic=baos.toByteArray();

            }     
            catch (Exception ee)    {
                System.out.println("Check internet connection please");
                socket.close(); 
                return;
            }
            byte[] cipherpic = cipher.doFinal(plainpic);

            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = new Date();
            System.out.println("Sending image " + dateFormat.format(date));

            try {
                while (true) {
                    sos.write(cipherpic); 

                } 
            }
            catch (EOFException ee) { 
                System.out.println("-------------- Done ----------"); 
                is.close();
            }

            sos.flush();
            sos.close();
            socket.close();
    }

  } 
}
```

**Client.java**

```
public class Client { 
  public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
    String fname = "image.jpg";


    SSLSocket sslsocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",15123);
    DataInputStream in = null;
    try{ in = new DataInputStream(sslsocket.getInputStream()); }
    catch (Exception ee)
    { System.out.println("Check connection please");
      sslsocket.close(); return;
    }
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fname);

    try
    {
        while (true)
       fos.write(in.readByte());
    }
    catch (EOFException ee)
    {  System.out.println("File transfer complete");
       in.close();
    }
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    sslsocket.close();

    public static String asHex (byte buf[]) {

        //Obtain a StringBuffer object
        StringBuffer strbuf = new StringBuffer(buf.length * 2);
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
            if (((int) buf[i] & 0xff) < 0x10)
                strbuf.append("0");
            strbuf.append(Long.toString((int) buf[i] & 0xff, 16));
        }
        // Return result string in Hexadecimal format
        return strbuf.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you think this code is doing? `while (true) {
                    sos.write(cipherpic); 

                } ` ? This is sending the same image forever to the client (or until the client runs out of memory, which will be sooner) Why would this ever result in an EOFException? There is no way that your code could ever print "Done".

Comment: You are writing the content of `cipherpic` to the outputstream in an infinite loop, which will never give an `EOFException` (which is for input anyway) .

Answer (score 0):

Look what's in your server:

```
        try {
            while (true) {
                sos.write(cipherpic); 

            } 
        }
        catch (EOFException ee) { 
            System.out.println("-------------- Done ----------"); 
            is.close();
        }
```

You will never get an EOFException, so you're writing cipherpic forever.

Comment: @johntan could you write it once?

Comment: you mean the cipherpic? Yes, I could get the file, but only after I killed the process when Server.java was running. However, when I click on the image, it gives me a "We can't open this file" message.

Comment: @johntan I mean why do you have a loop here instead of just writing cipherpic once?